# complex indicator variable problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider a group of n>=4 people, numbered from 1 to n. For each pair (i,j) with $i \not =j$ person i and person j are friends, with probability p. Friendships are independent for different pairs. These n people are seated around a round table. For convenience, assume that the chairs are numbered from to 1 to n, clockwise, with n located next to 1, and that person i seated in chair i. In particular, person 1 and person n are seated next to each other.

If a person is friends with both people sitting next to him/her, we say this person is happy. Let H be the total number of happy people. Express your answers in terms of p and/or n

It says Lets $I_i$, be a random variable indicating whether the person seated in chair i is happy or not ($I_i$ = 1 if person i is happy and 0 otherwise). Find $E[I_i]$ for i = 1,2,...,n

I calculated $E(I_i)=p^2$ and $E[H]=n*p^2.$ I'm stuck on the parts where I have to calculate the following

1. $E[I_k^2]$  for any k in set 1,2,..n.

2.$E[I_iJ_j]$ for $i \not =j$

3.under the convention $I_n+_1=I_1$, find $E[I_iI_n+_1]$

4.Var(H)

Comment: i tried to solve it by myself but need verification of answers below
1. p^2
2.p^3
3.p^4
4.n(b+2*c+a*b-4*d)
are the answers correct?

Comment: Can anyone hep me out here please and verify my answers in the comment section?